# Call to action: Let's tidy up the currency tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

As already previously discussed in [this question, its answer and comments](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/what-is-the-currency-tag-for) the currency tag is as ambiguous as they get.

This is the tag description:

> usefulness of this tag is under debate
>   If your question is about whether a saying or usage is currently in active use, consider using [contemporary-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contemporary-english).
>
> If your question is about money, consider keeping this tag, or using only other tags that categorize your question.
>
> See [this Meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/what-is-the-currency-tag-for) for the discussion.

We can see that even the description is rather unhelpful and advises already against using it.

In the previous meta question *two mods and everything that's up-voted agrees* on using the tag [contemporary-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contemporary-english) for everything regarding the currency of use and the tag [currency](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) for questions regarding money. For further clarity AndrewLeach suggested using the tag [money](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) and make [currency](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) a synonym.

Thus, I suggest a two-pieced approach.

1. Edit the two tag wikis - *The tag wikis have been updated.*
2. Go through all 78 questions tagged with [currency](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency), evaluate if they regard money. If they do, re-tag them to [money](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) as AndrewLeach suggested. If they don't re-tag them to [contemporary-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contemporary-english). - We did it.

Comment: Once this is done, it might also be worth creating the tag [money] and making [currency] a synonym of that so that nothing can actually be tagged "currency".

Comment: @AndrewLeach I like that idea.

Comment: In fact, I suppose splitting the current [currency] questions into [contemporary-english] and [money] would help identify the questions which still needed doing. Once there are none, the synonym could be created.

Comment: @AndrewLeach even better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the questions have been sorted into [contemporary-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contemporary-english) and [money](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money), the final stage has been completed with the creation of tag synonyms.

Questions which are attempted with [currency](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) will get [money](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money).

Questions where the user attempts to use `curr` to start something to do with "current English" will **also** suggest [contemporary-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contemporary-english) because it has a new synonym of [current-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-usage).

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to edit this post if you edited more questions.

- [Why “off the table” is not included in major English dictionaries while “on the table” is shown as an idiom in all of them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272784) - Done!
- [€10 = "ten euro" or "ten euros"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13551) - Done!
- [Is “She-economy” getting currency?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125598) - Done!
- [Is “It’s not unheard-of to do” not-an-unusual expression in day-to-day conversation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249645) - Done!
- [Is “pre-spin” a common word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279057) - Done!
- [Is the word "mid-shelf" applicable to any merchandize being sold at retail shops more than liquor?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132792) - Done!
- [Lean in and lean out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189488) - Done!
- [Is ‘scooplet’ a popular word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277889) - Done!
- [Is ‘on (in) a tear’ a popular idiom?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116493) - Done!
- [What is the correct way to write a range of dollar figures?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37952) - Done!
- [Is “cheese-stick operation, manufacturing, building current word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164013) - Done!
- [Pluralization rule is different when we say, 10 pound note and 10 pounds?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24134) - Done!
- [Is there a list of plural names of currencies?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147689) - Done!
- [How to write £1 million where style guide clashes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322233) - Done!
- [Why is the unit of measure placed before the value for currencies? Are there other measures where the unit precedes value?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34013) - Done!
- [What does Mr. Trump’s “inner rabbit” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308939) - Done!
- [Is “release one’s butt cheeks” a euphemism?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167909) - Done!
- [What does “triple down” in “Trump triples down on George W. Bush’s responsibility for 9/11”mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280968) - Done!
- [What does ‘Reverse fig leaf” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185326) - Done!
- [How to say the total amount?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65289) - Done!
- [Is “over-babble” a common word usable in day-to-day conversation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246416) - Done!
- [Does ‘legit intel” pass as a usual English word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125235) - Done!
- [Is “I’m Mike” scam a popular metonym of "grandparent" scam?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169805) - Done!
- [Is “play chess when others are playing checkers,” a well-known / well-used phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126603) - Done!
- [What does “literary stylist” mean? Is it a characteristic or a profession?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216121) - Done!
- [Is it common to use "where" after "a time" as a relative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313189) - Done!
- [What does “Awesome” mean when you are complimented by an Apple-shop salesclerk on your answer to a barrage of his questions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123622) - Done!
- [Can the word, “OK’er,” be used in other area than copy editing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279649) - Done!
- [Word or concept for "credit system" in context of "topping up" an account](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180623) - Done!
- [The origin of the word, aw-shucks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349045) - Done!
- [What does “for comfort” in “too fast (close / hot/ warm / crammed) for comfort” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266367) - Done!
- [Is “There are perks, but there’s also baggage” a popular English adage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312240) - Done!
- [Is the word, “kinda-sorta” accepted as a normal word to be used in writing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166834) - Done!
- [What does “I really get the juices flowing when I’m driving” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125886) - Done!
- [Is there a word for the most granular parts of currency, eg, cents, pence, etc?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223121) - Done!
- [What does “The Cruz-Trump relationship goes solid #TBT” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338678) - Done!
- [What does “crawl over a pile of hot coals” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326797) - Done!
- [What does “medical scare” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275999) - Done!
- [What words describe the relation between "dollars" and "cents"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319060) - Done!
- [Who are “Security moms”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205294) - Done!
- [What does President Obama's “pro-knowledge” remark mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326127) - Done!
- [Who are “the perks people”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216165) - Done!
- [Is “Ur-moment” a normal English expression?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187743) - Done!
- [What is the provenance of “ring the cherries”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198675) - Done!
- [What does “media (news) disruptor” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196184) - Done!
- [The usage of “banzai”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196188) - Done!
- [Is ‘celebvocate’ gaining currency in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119177) - Done!
- [What does “Live in one’s own skin” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220401) - Done!
- [Case of USD — "United States Dollar" or "United States dollar"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26378) - Done!
- [Should it be 10 US$ or US$ 10?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26400) - Done!
- [What does ‘Konrad Lorentz’s observation was “one sentence”’ mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171811) - Done!
- [What does “the New York egoscape” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319602) - Done!
- [Is “Click bait” an Internet buzzword? How can I rephrase it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210357) - Done!
- [Dollar sign necessary in "$16 LD"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100404) - Done!
- [How to correctly write a range of currency?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17072) - Done!
- [Are “Real class” and “Paper class” well-received pair words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204281) - Done!
- [Is the phrase “Corporate Daddy” getting currency, or is it just a one-off coinage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180061) - Done!
- [What does “Small words” in “They are small words that reflect a dark and negative point of view.”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117838) - Done!
- [What does “Retail politics” mean? Is it an established political term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305046) - Done!
- [Is “Grey tsunami” a mere metaphor, or acknowledged phrase to represent for accelerated global increase of old age population?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212335) - Done!
- [Is the word, ‘nerdocracy’ just a nonce word, or becoming current?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161735) - Done!
- [Is “two-Perrier” lunch a businessmen’s buzz word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221181) - Done!
- [What does “soft bigotry of low expectations” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169433) - Done!
- [What does “Wonk gap” mean in brief?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126146) - Done!
- [What does “Empty dress” exactly mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172802) - Done!
- [Does the words, “Love interests” and “Love intelligence” have a special meaning other than plain “love affair” and “love gossip”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129304) - Done!
- [Is “un-grown-up” a common, or not so common word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158270) - Done!
- [What does “cheffed-up” in “Traditional ramen that hasn’t been cheffed-up” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218235) - Done!
- [Is “closed press (remark / ceremony / meeting)” a popular English word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122830) - Done!
- [What does “Love arrives with a bonk on the head with a balloon” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126754) - Done!
- [Is the phrase, “Let ‘em up easy” Abraham Lincoln’s one-off phrase or an obsolete idiom?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119051) - Done!
- [Is “since-folded (TV network)” an accustomed English word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187551) - Done!
- [What does “fall for a bluff” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265330) - Done!
- [Are monetary values plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71266) - Done!
- [English term that groups notes and coins of a currency](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12701) - Done!
- [Does the expression, “As sound as a pound” still holds its currency?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186929) - Done!
- [Is “You ain’t seen nothin’ yet” a common or respectable English expression?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215264) - Done!
- [What does “show some (a little) leg” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/191747) - Done!
- [How to spell out dollars and cents](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70315) - Done!

Comment: The first 50 links (down through the one for "Should it be 10 US$ or US$ 10?") and the last 10 links (up through "Love arrives with a bonk on the head") have been updated from "currency" to either "money" or "contemporary-english". I haven't checked the ones between those two points.

Comment: I just finished the last few. Thanks everyone who helped.