# “Why is a raven like a writing desk?”

Tags: discussion, tags

The above is a famous riddle from *Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland*
by Lewis Carroll,
[[ref1]](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/65800-mad-hatter-why-is-a-raven-like-a-writing-desk), [[ref2]](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-2083,00.html), [[ref3]](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5872014/the-answer-to-the-most-famous-unanswerable-fantasy-riddle), [[ref4-∞]](https://www.google.com/#q=%E2%80%9CWhy+is+a+raven+like+a+writing+desk?%E2%80%9D&*&spf=2002), …

But seriously,

## How is [writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) *unlike* [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style)?

I recently reviewed [this suggested edit](//english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/227203),
which added the [writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) tag to [this question](//english.stackexchange.com/q/65793/26083),
which already had the [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) tag. 
And I scratched my head and looked them up:

> [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style)     18 followers, 732 questions
>   Questions related to the use of proper writing style in English
>
> ---
>
> The style of a sentence, phrase, or construction,
>   is its general expression of meaning as a whole,
>   apart from the actual categorical meaning of the constituent words.
>
> Use this tag for questions asking about the style
>   of a particular sentence, phrase, or construction.

Sounds good.

> [writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing)      22 followers, 387 questions
>   This tag is for questions specifically related to written English.
>
> ---
>
> #### Examples of questions using this tag
>
> - [If an insertion in parentheses ends with a smiley,
>     how do I distinguish between the two?](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/4893)
> - [Should you always use the accent in foreign words like “résumé”?](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/177)
>
> (Cont’d) …                  <sub>[Order changed for effect.]</sub>

Ah, I thought, [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) refers to
the thoughtful authoring, composing, preparing and rendering of
ideas, information, knowledge, etc., into prose words (or, perhaps, verse)
intended for non-vocal delivery and/or presentation,
while [writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) refers to the physical/visual representation of text. 
But the list goes on:

> … (Cont’d)
>
> - [Capitalisation of nouns in English in the 17th and 18th centuries](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/10522)
> - [Why, in old books, are dates often given with the years redacted?](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/9479)
> - [Which variant of English should I use
>     when my target audience is the world?](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/8964)

and so I wondered, why isn’t [capitalization](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capitalization) the most appropriate tag
for a question about capitalization? 
Why isn’t [date](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) the most appropriate tag for a question about dates? 
And why aren’t [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) and/or [dialects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects)
the most appropriate tags
for a question about which variant of English to use?

And finally, if we need tag(s) for the physical/visual representation of text,
what’s wrong with [typography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) (8 followers, 132 questions),
[orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) (26 followers, 1.1k questions) and
[symbols](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols) (4 followers, 97 questions)?

A quick scan of recent [questions tagged [writing]](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing)
reveals questions about

- document (e.g., bibliography) formatting
  (which should probably be covered by [style-manuals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-manuals),
  although that has no tag wiki / usage guidance yet),
- formality (e.g., use of pronouns in papers for publication) 
  (which should probably be covered by [formality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formality)
  and/or [style-manuals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-manuals)),
- politeness (e.g., salutations in letters and emails) ([politeness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness)),
- indentation ([typography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography)),
- word choice (an issue for spoken English as well as written,
  covered by [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice)),
- use of “a” *vs.* “an” before symbols
  (which is an issue for spoken English as well as written,
  and probably covered by [symbols](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols)),
- punctuation (which is also a tag: 44 followers, 1.9k questions),

etc. 
It’s a tag about everything, so it’s a tag about nothing. 
(By the way, of the 387 questions tagged [writing],
[52 are also tagged [writing-style]](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style+writing).

So, should the [writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) tag be deleted? 
Or should it be defined to something useful? 
(I guess questions currently bearing that tag
would need to be revisited/re-evaluated either way.)

---

Related: [Should the typography tag and typesetting tag be merged?](//english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3783/26083)

Comment: Oh, the irony. When I clicked on [Post Your Question], I was presented with a CAPTCHA featuring [this](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/englishmeta/img/captcha.png) image.

Comment: P.S. I’m a visitor to EL&U (and occasionally ELL); I live on Planet [SU].  On Meta Super User, punny/witty titles for discussions of dubious/obsolete tags are *de rigueur*.  I apologize if my attempt at levity is unwelcome here.

Comment: We did something similar recently [sorting out "currency"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9468/call-to-action-lets-tidy-up-the-currency-tag) -- which was disambiguated into [contemporary-english] and [money]. The questions' current tags need to be sorted (removing [writing] and substituting something else if necessary) before [writing] is deleted and blacklisted, if blacklisting is desirable. 387 questions is a tall order, and would cause significant upheaval on the front page.

Comment: 'writing' is not as vague or meaningless as 'grammar' or 'English'. Yes, it could easily be removed from many questions but I don't think it is terrible.

Comment: I think 'orthography' is apt, but not everyone will know that term. That said, the 'writing' tag is not used as an appropriate synonym for 'orthography'.

Comment: _wants to give answer so bad_

Comment: Why? Be-CAWS!     :-)     (I actually just thought of that.)

Comment: _can't... stand... it ... I KNOW! I KNOW!! I KNOW!!!_

Comment: They both have quills, although one's are used for fancy flights and the other's for flights of fancy.

Comment: Oh... @PeterShor.

Comment: Um, did you ***look*** at [[ref2\]](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-2083,00.html) and [[ref3\]](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5872014/the-answer-to-the-most-famous-unanswerable-fantasy-riddle) in the first line of the question?

Answer (score 2):

"Writing" should definitely disappear. For the rare question for which it would be appropriate, for questions on written registers of English and their differences from spoken English, "written-english" would be a much clearer tag. Or maybe it could be renamed, I just don't know how many questions would then be mistagged.

"Orthography" is a separate topic. I'd suggest that it be used for discuss how the Latin script has come to be used to transcribe spoken English. This topic has a lot of history and quirks and many very interesting questions.

I've suggested this for the wiki for writing-style because [the current wiki](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/writing-style/info) doesn't really make sense. But the edit was knocked back. Anyone want to make some improvements to it and then we can try again?

> Writing style is hard to define definitively - but when you see good style, you know it. Good style is elegant rather than clumsy, powerful rather than weak. It takes practice to develop.
>
> Use this tag for questions asking about the style of a particular sentence, phrase, or construction. But be warned, many of these questions are what we call Primarily Opinion Based, and are likely to be closed.